# D3 DataMaps: OnClick Events on Bubbles

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, datamaps

I am following the datamaps docs and I am trying to set an onClick listener to the bubbles I am rendering on the svg. Now, the *svg div* has the following sub tags:

```
<svg>
  <g id class="datamaps-subunits">..</g>
  <g id class="bubbles">..</g>
</svg>
```

The docs say this should be done in the following way, for the countries listed on the map:

```
done: function(datamap) {
            datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunits').on('click', function() {
              alert("hello");  
            });
        }
```

And this works fine, while trying to click on particular regions on the map.

Trying to attach the same listener to *bubbles* class does nothing..

```
done: function(datamap) {
            datamap.svg.selectAll('.bubbles').on('click', function() {
                alert("hello"); 
            });
        }
```

Comment: Is something else in front of the `.bubbles` elements so that the click event doesn't get through?

Comment: Something affected by z-index you reckon?

Comment: There's no `z-index` in SVG, the order in which you add elements is the order in which they are displayed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the time `done` runs, `bubbles` haven't been added yet since `bubbles` is a plugin.

`new Datamap` returns an object with a d3 selection at `svg`:

```
var map = new Datamap({...}); 
//add bubbles
map.bubbles(bubbleData);
//handle bubble clicks
map.svg.selectAll('.bubbles').on('click', function() {...});
```

That should work for the first batch of bubbles.

If you are dynamically adding bubbles and don't want to reset the listeners, you can use jQuery event delegation to handle the dynamic bubbles:

```
$(map.svg[0][0]).on('click', '.bubbles', function(e) {
  //handle click here as well
});
```