# D3 DataMaps: OnClick Events on Bubbles Passing in Attributes of Bubble

Tags: javascript, d3.js, datamaps

I'm using D3 and DataMaps with bubbles. I want to add custom actions when someone clicks on a bubble. These actions require passing in attributes of the bubble like the bubble's name.

How do I pass the bubble's name into an on click event for that bubble?

```
map.svg.selectAll('.bubbles').on('click', function(bubble) {
    console.log(bubble.name);
});
```

This code snippet does not work. I get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I'm following a [similar example](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps#events) from the documentation for passing in attributes of the geography:

```
datamap.svg.selectAll('.datamaps-subunit').on('click', function(geography) {
    alert(geography.properties.name);
});
```

I have also read [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215394/d3-datamaps-onclick-events-on-bubbles) that does not answer my question about passing in attributes of the bubble.

Comment: what do you get if you replace the console.log() with `console.log(bubble);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
map.svg.selectAll('.bubbles').on('click', function(bubble) {
    console.log(bubble.name);
});
```

try:

```
d3.selectAll(".datamaps-bubble").on('click', function(bubble) {
    console.log(bubble);
});
```

hope this works!

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!